Spectral Permanence Remark in Murphy's C*-algebras
In Murphy's $C^{*}$-algebras book, he states theorem $2.1.11$ which is that if $\mathfrak{B} \subset \mathfrak{A}$ are $C^{*}$-algebras with $\mathfrak{A}$ unital such that $1_{\mathfrak{A}} \in \mathfrak{B}$, then: $$\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b)  = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \: \: \forall b \in \mathfrak{B}.$$
I understand the proof without issue, but then on pg. 44 he claims in an off-hand remark the Spectral Permanence theorem.  That is, if $\mathfrak{B} \subset \mathfrak{A}$ are any $C^{*}$-algebras, then infact: $$\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b) \cup \{0\}  = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \cup \{0\}\: \: \forall b \in \mathfrak{B}.$$  His proof is the following: Suppose that $\mathfrak{A}$ is unital and that $\mathfrak{B} \oplus \mathbb{C}1_{\mathfrak{A}} = \mathfrak{A}$.  The claim is that the above equation holds in this special case.
$\textbf{Case 1:}$ First suppose that $\mathfrak{B}$ isn't itself unital.  Clearly we have an isomorphism $\overset{\sim}{\mathfrak{B}} \cong \mathfrak{A}$ by $(b,\lambda) \mapsto b+\lambda 1_{\mathfrak{A}}$ so then since isomorphisms preserve spectra: $$\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b) := \sigma_{\overset{\sim}{\mathfrak{B}}}(b) = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \: \: \forall b \in \mathfrak{B} \implies \sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \cup \{0\} \: \: \forall b \in \mathfrak{B}.$$
$\textbf{Case 2}:$ Now suppose that $\mathfrak{B}$ has a unit $e \in \mathfrak{B}$ where $e \neq 1_{\mathfrak{A}}$.  Then he says that for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, we have $\lambda e-b$ is invertible in $\mathfrak{B}$ if and only if $\lambda 1_{\mathfrak{A}}-b$ is invertible in $\mathfrak{A}$.  Hence then: $$\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \cup \{0\} \: \: \forall b \in \mathfrak{B}.$$ $\textit{This is the part I dont understand}$.  I can't seem to see why this if and only if statement is true, so if someone could explain that would be great!
I do however see how this proves it for the general case though.  Indeed, we can assume $\mathfrak{A}$ is unital by passing to $\overset{\sim}{\mathfrak{A}}$ if needed. Then we have from the above work that: $$\sigma_{\mathfrak{B}}(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_{\mathfrak{B} \oplus \mathbb{C}1_{\mathfrak{A}}}(b) \cup \{0\} = \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(b) \cup \{0\}$$ where the first equality is from the above work and the second equality is from theorem 2.1.11.  However, I do not understand how $\textbf{case 2}$ is proven.

We start by noting that $(1_A - e)b = b - b = 0 = b(1_A - e)$ for all $b \in B$.
Assume first that $\lambda e - b$ is invertible in $B$ with inverse $f \in B$. Then $f + \lambda^{-1}(1_A - e)$ is the inverse of $\lambda 1_A - b$ in $A$. Indeed,
$$\begin{split}
[f + \lambda^{-1}(1_A - e)](\lambda 1_A - b) &= [f + \lambda^{-1}(1_A - e)][\lambda (1_A - e) + (\lambda e - b)]\\
&= \lambda f(1_A - e) + f(\lambda e - b) + (1_A - e) + \lambda^{-1}(1_A - e)(\lambda e - b)\\
&= 0 + e + (1_A - e) + 0\\
&= 1_A
\end{split}$$
And similarly $(\lambda 1_A - b)[f + \lambda^{-1}(1_A - e)] = 1_A$.
Now, assume $\lambda 1_A - b$ is invertible in $A = B \oplus \mathbb{C}1_A$ with inverse $f + \eta 1_A$ for some $f \in B$ and $\eta \in \mathbb{C}$. Then,
$$1_A = (\lambda 1_A - b)(f + \eta 1_A) = (-bf + \lambda f - \eta b) + \lambda \eta 1_A$$
Since $A = B \oplus \mathbb{C}1_A$, this implies $\lambda \eta = 1$ and $-bf + \lambda f - \eta b = 0$. Similarly, $-fb + \lambda f - \eta b = 0$. But then,
$$\begin{split}
(\lambda e - b)(f + \eta e) &= \lambda f + \lambda \eta e - bf - \eta b\\
&= \lambda f + e + (- \lambda f + \eta b) - \eta b\\
&= e
\end{split}$$
Similarly, $(f + \eta e)(\lambda e - b) = e$, so $f + \eta e$ is the inverse of $\lambda e - b$ in $B$ and thus $\lambda e - b$ is invertible in $B$.

The intuition in thinking about this is that $A = B \oplus \mathbb{C}1_A = B \oplus \mathbb{C}(1_A - e)$. But in the latter form the two direct summands are actually orthogonal, so multiplication happens pointwise, that is, $A \simeq B \oplus \mathbb{C}$ where the direct sum is not just a vector space, but as an algebra.
